# How to work on same tkinter window from different python file?

Tags: python, tkinter

For example if I have a `main.py` file which has a `root = tk.Tk()` line for main window of GUI. 
 And another file `menu.py` which I want to use to add menu bar to the root window in `main.py`.

Comment: You can define a function with an argument, the `root` window, in `menu.py`, then you can call this function with the `root` window as the argument in `main.py` after importing `menu`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really easy so don't worry.

First ensure that `main.py` and `menu.py` are in the same folder,

then at the beginning of `main.py` add `from menu import *`.

This should import all the data and python code from the other file so you can work in that file as if you were working in the main one.

Comment: It's giving me error `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`

Comment: Can you update your question with some code? But this error occurs when root isn't defined, so try checking if you defined root correctly.

Comment: I did it by passing arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to just import main.py into menu.py.

Put this at the top of your menu.py code:

```
from main import *
```

now you will be able to access everything from main.py.

so you could do:

```
root.title("new title from menu.py")
```

Comment: Giving same error again `NameError: name 'root' is not defined`.  Can you please share some link or any working code example.

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I have a main.py file which has a root = tk.Tk() line
> for main window of GUI

Absolutely!.

> And another file menu.py which I want to use to add menu bar to the
> root window in main.py

No problem.

Try this for instance:

In `main.py`.

```
from tkinter import *
import menu


window = Tk()
window.title('Main Window')
menu.create_menu(window)

icon = PhotoImage(file= 'p1.png')
window.iconphoto(True , icon)

window.mainloop()
```

In `menu.py`. You don't need to add `Tk()` window and `mainloop()`. The `main.py` will care of this.

Create `create_menu()` function. Add parameter `master`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu


# create a menubar
def create_menu(master):
    menubar = Menu(master)
    master.config(menu=menubar)

    # create a menu
    file_menu = Menu(menubar)

    # add a menu item to the menu
    file_menu.add_command(
        label='Exit',
        command=master.destroy
    )


    # add the File menu to the menubar
    menubar.add_cascade(
        label="File",
        menu=file_menu
    )
```

Screenshot: you will see title on  Main Window.

[image]